# Integrating Vaadin with D3

Tags: d3.js, gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to integrate this d3 chart into a vaadin aplication
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373

I am familiar with vaadin, but I have never developed an widget or anything on client side

So, my question is:
1) How difficult it is? (be honest!) 
2) What would be your approach?

Comment: I am not sure what is d2?

Answer (score 2):

To integrate D3 chart you can use Web Component integration mechanism.

See the tutorial on the page: [Demystifying Web Components](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/demystifying-web-components)

Instead of third party charts you can use [Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/charts)

Comment: My experience with [dCharts](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/dcharts-widget) add-on were positive, too.